# Azure ASP.NET MVC: avoiding ~3 minute Request Timeout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to download a 100MB file from an ASP.NET MVC controller, but I'm getting timeouts after 3-4 minutes (it varies).

```
    public ActionResult DownloadMyFile() {
        Server.ScriptTimeout = 60 * 60; // 1 hr timeout for downloading myfile

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile");
        Response.BufferOutput = false;

        this.CloudBlobContainer
              .GetBlobReference("myfile")
              .DownloadToStream(Response.OutputStream);

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

- This doesn't happen on my local machine running it as an ASP.NET MVC application directly, I suspect this is something in the azure stack (the IIS server???).
- The timeout appears to be time-based, not file-size based.
- The timeout does NOT return an error to browsers, they think they got the whole file and stop with a report of success (!!!).
- The file is currently hosted on Azure Storage, but could come from another source in the future, so I don't want to just redirect to a blob storage URL.
- This is a rarely used admin-only method and doesn't need to be optimized/complicated to be async or whatever unless this is really the only way to do it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem... Yes an admin only method that I only want to run a couple of times. I just want a simple brute force way to temporarily increase my timeout limit. I am getting blank pages returned after about 3-4 minutes at the moment...

Comment: Me too.. strange issue, it just times out in 3 mins no matter what i do. The solution given below doesn't works

Comment: @Seth Did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to increase the execution timeout in the web.config.

The following changes the timeout to 1 hour (3600 seconds):

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime 
      executionTimeout="3600"
    />
```

[The default is 110 seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout.aspx)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, and the timeout is closer to 3.5 or 4 minutes than 110 seconds (~2 minutes), so I suspect this is not the problem.